# Iframe file uploading and NoScript plugin

Tags: javascript, noscript

I have a form with ajax file uploading. Javascript creates iframe with a form, moves input with the file into the form and submit the form.

This works without any problem, but popular NoScript plugin in Firefox thinks that it's XSS and turn my POST request into GET. So it doesn't work. Is there any possibility to circumvent this problem?

Code (uses jQuery)

```
function add_input_file(div) {
  var input = $("<input>").attr("type", "file").attr("name", "file");
  input.appendTo(div);
  input.change(function() {
    $(this).off();
    var iframe = $("<iframe>");
    iframe.appendTo($("body"));
    iframe.load(function() {
      $(this).off();
      var input = $(this).data("input");
      var form = $("<form>").attr("method", "post").attr("action", "/send").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data").attr("accept-charset", "UTF-8");
      form.appendTo($(this).contents().find("body"));
      input.appendTo(form);
      add_input_file($("#att"));
      form.submit();
    });
  });
}
$(function() {
  add_input_file($("#att"));
})
```

Comment: Can you post the javascript code?

Comment: Rather than creating the IFrame and Form dynamically have them as part of the page's HTML <iframe id="ajaxpost" class="hidden" src="ajaxpost.htm" />

Comment: The problem is there can be different numbers of uploading files. So I have to make iframes dynamically.

Comment: Did you try setting a source for the iframe? Currently it doesn't have one, so noscript might considers it cross-site because the src of the iframe isn't pointing to the same site.

Comment: @Ximik This code would not work at all with NoScript, what with this code being java- **script** and all... so there isn't a solution to your problem that still gives you a dynamic multi-uploader. You need scripts for that, and NoScript is blocking scripts.

Comment: @AVee. hm Seems like special page with the form works fine. Thank you for the idea. However this is still rather ugly like for me.

Comment: @Chris Noscript is on, but javascript from the site is accepted. This is my situation.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a code fix but I use this [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) to do ajax uploading. I've tested the [sample](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) with Firefox and NoScript installed, everything ran fine.

If you don't want to use a custom plugin, take a look to the [source code](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js) to see how it's done.

Comment: This plugin uses special futures of HTML5. And so it doesn't work in old browsers (for old browsers it uses iframe just like my code).

Comment: Did you try it? Maybe they do something just a little bit different to make it works with old browsers as well.

Comment: In fact my code is somehow based on this plugin. I've just removed all that uses javascript file access instead of iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you display a simple file form at `<noscript>`, since script has been turnned off, you cannot solve the problem by use more scripts.